# Faster query for joining 4 tables or more in mysql

Tags: mysql

I saw this format of selecting from multiple tables with multiple conditions somewhere and I have been implementing this for many years. What I want to know is if there's any way we can make it any faster.
Background of the query: I am selecting messages from messages table b/w student and tutors for a job posted in jobs table by the student.
Tutor's info is stored in tutorinfo table and studentinfo is stored in studentinfo table.

Please also tell what kind of join is this. Someone told me it's a cross join but I am not sure. I didn't know about joins until recently but never had to. This format has served me for quite some time now. I am not sure how using the join formatting would make it better, if any better.

Here is the present query::

```
SELECT 
messages.* ,  
tutorinfo.id as tutor_id, 
jobs.student_id as student_id, jobs.job_title
from messages, tutorinfo, studentinfo, jobs where
messages.job_id= jobs.id and jobs.student_id = '3' and messages.thread_id = '2' and        messages.tutor_id = tutorinfo.id and messages.job_id = jobs.id and studentinfo.id=jobs.student_id
```

Comment: [Don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Try to get into the habit of using explicit JOIN syntax. It's much more readable for you, us, and (in some instances) MySQL too. And, as others have pointed out, don't include tables that are irrelevant to your result set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your select statement written in a more modern style.  In this style you can see the joins (note they are all inner joins).  You can tell they are inner joins (in both our queries) because the columns joined on are joined by an equal.  In your method to have a cross join or an outer join you need special formatting (instead of just a `=`), with the "join" format you use special syntax.

```
SELECT m.*, 
       t.id as tutor_id, 
       j.student_id as student_id, j.job_title
from messages m
join jobs j on m.job_id = j.job_id
join studentinfo s on j.student_id = s.id
join tutorinfo t on m.tutor_id = t.id
where j.student_id = '3' and m.thread_id = '2'
```

One thing is clear -- studentinfo is not used you can take that out.
Other than that and adding indexes to all the columns which are used as joins I don't see much in the way of optimization.

```
SELECT m.*, 
       t.id as tutor_id, 
       j.student_id as student_id, j.job_title
from messages m
join jobs j on m.job_id = j.job_id
join tutorinfo t on m.tutor_id = t.id
where j.student_id = '3' and m.thread_id = '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use MySQL JOINS**

[image]

```
    SELECT
     jobs.`id` AS jobs_id,
     jobs.`job_title` AS jobs_job_title,
     messages.`id` AS messages_id,
     messages.`job_id` AS messages_job_id,
     messages.`thread_id` AS messages_thread_id,
     messages.`tutor_id` AS messages_tutor_id,
     messages.`student_id` AS messages_student_id,
     tutorinfo.`id` AS tutorinfo_id
FROM
     `messages` messages INNER JOIN `tutorinfo` tutorinfo ON messages.`tutor_id` = tutorinfo.`id`
     INNER JOIN `jobs` jobs ON messages.`job_id` = jobs.`id`  WHERE jobs.student_id = '3' AND messages.thread_id = '2'
```

Also Take a look at these stuffs

[**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

[**Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Why are you joining on studentinfo?  It is never used.

Comment: Sorry @Hogan since user1849091 has mentioned about the studentinfo table....that why i joined that too....see my updation.....

Answer (score 0):

This was going to be a comment to supplement @Hogan's answer but I'm posting separately. In Mysql `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` are all syntatic equivalents. `,` and `INNER JOIN` are semantically equivalent in absence of a join condition however `,` has a lower precedence.

In the original query the join conditions have been placed in the where clause. The Mysql query optimiser probably comes up with an optimised query plan for the present query and avoids cross joins and filtering on the product by using `INNER JOINS` in an optimised order. However, by rewording slightly you can make the join conditions explicit, force the read order and reduce the work the query optimiser needs to do. Perhaps this is of neglible performance benefit. You'd have to profile to see.

```
SELECT m.*, 
       t.id as tutor_id, 
       j.student_id as student_id, j.job_title
from messages m
STRAIGHT_JOIN jobs j on m.job_id = j.job_id and j.student_id = '3'
STRAIGHT_JOIN tutorinfo t on m.tutor_id = t.id
where m.thread_id = '2'
```

`STRAIGHT_JOIN` is similar to `JOIN` but the left table is read before the right. From the Mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html):

> The join optimizer calculates the order in which tables should be
>   joined. The table read order forced by LEFT JOIN or STRAIGHT_JOIN
>   helps the join optimizer do its work much more quickly, because there
>   are fewer table permutations to check